# How can I query users by custom role?

Tags: wp-query, user-roles

How can I query custom user roles created by plugins?

For example, my install has a 'customer' role, but using the code below delivers nothing.

```
$blogusers = get_users( array(
    'role' => 'customer',
) );

foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
    echo esc_html( $user->display_name ) . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do what you're asking - your code worked for me on a WooCommerce install. Maybe the label is not the same as the role slug - you can use [`get_editable_roles()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_editable_roles) to get all available roles to check this.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee... Thanks. I'm unclear about get_editable_roles() - read it only works in admin, and I'm doing a front-end query. I'd previously queried to get available roles (which I assume is the same as those shown in the dropdown in admin screen), but don't know if they're all editable. The query in my original post works fine for the default roles, but not custom ones.

Comment: You could check against the `global $wp_roles` variable - that will give you both roles and capabilities.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee... Thanks (says he with all the enthusiasm of someone presented with another thing he doesn't understand and is thus shelving what he was doing in favor of another trip to google to learn more about the 'global $wp_roles variable'. ;-)